# Pass an argument to a function in groupby aggregate pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dummy data frame as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5],
    'workday':[1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1,2]
    })
```

I have these two aggregate functions

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last'])

df.groupby('ID').agg('nth',-2)
```

I tried `lambda x: x.nth(-2)` but it says `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'nth'`
I want to pass them at once in one groupby aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

One idea:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(['first','last', lambda x: x.iloc[-2] if len(x) > 1 else np.nan])
print (df)
   workday                
     first last <lambda_0>
ID                        
1        1    2        1.0
2        1    3        2.0
3        1    1        NaN
4        1    1        NaN
5        1    2        1.0
```